# 2002-2006 Science art inventor cartoon show of Disney

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

Between 2002-2006, I saw this cartoon show about a kid who loves both science and art and would make a lot of inventions during the cartoon series. All I remember is that it was a Disney cartoon series, but this was during the time when *Jimmy Neutron* was aired (Nickelodeon), and *Dexter's Laboratory* (Cartoon Network), and this cartoon series is supposed to be Disney's competing cartoon to the other TV networks with some variation. She loves making inventions on science and art.

Comment: Possible that it could be Kim Possible?

Comment: @NKCampbell, thanks but n. KimPossible was about saving the world from villains and stuff. The theme of the show revolved around inventing something new every episode. Curious thing about her is that she likes science, but is also very artistic.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GadgeteerGenius (warning, TV Tropes link!) might be useful, although nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: And if you could be thinking of a non human character, Tinkerbell from Disney's Fairies is said to be an inventor according to the TV Tropes link.

Comment: How about Gadget Hackwrench from Chip 'n Dale Rescue Rangers; or Gretchen Grundler from Recess. (found by quick digging with searches). But neither series starred that character, so I guess not.

Comment: The only other cartoons with a female lead that aired on the Disney Channel around that period would be Pepper Ann or The Proud Family, I think. (Or Lizzie McGuire at a stretch, though it's mostly live action).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be [*Evil Con Carne*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419322/?ref_=ttls_li_tt) (2003-2004), a spin off from [*Grim & Evil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grim_%26_Evil) although it is a Cartoon Network show. The character you are looking for would be Major Doctor Ghastly:

> Major Doctor Andedonia J. Ghastly is the lover and mad scientist of Evil Con Carne. She used to be the second assistant to Professor Death Ray Eyes and decided to apply for Hector Con Carne. She instantly fell in love with Hector for seven years. Ghastly is the most optimistic of the crew since she would rather let her love towards Hector bloom instead of helping Hector achieve his goal of world domination.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, List of *Evil Con Carne* characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Evil_Con_Carne_characters)</sub>

[image: Major Doctor Ghastly]

Comment: Im quite familiar. Bubby character. But shes not the kid,im sad to say.

Comment: @imaginedragons01 It seemed to match some but not all aspects but was worth a try. I'll keep looking around.